# Custom query for displaying WordPress custom post types that are more than 8 months old from current date

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I'm using the following custom query in Wordpress within a for-loop that enables me to create a tabbed archive for the previous 8 months of the custom post type I've created for 'news'.

This works perfectly however I wish to then show every older post under the heading 'Older news. I'm struggling to figure out how to separate the posts that are older than 8 months from the current date at any one time.

Can anyone advise me as to a custom query structure that would enable me to do this.

Here's the code i use to output the CPTs in their relevant containers.

```
<?php for($i = $this_month-1; $i > $this_month-8; $i--) :
        if($i==-1){$m=11;}
        if($i==-2){$m=10;}
        if($i==-3){$m=9;}
        if($i==-4){$m=8;}
        if($i==-5){$m=7;}
        if($i==-6){$m=6;}
        if($i==-7){$m=5;}
        if($i==-8){$m=4;}
        else{$m=$i;}

        query_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'monthnum'=>$m
        ) );  
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
<?php 
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
    query_posts( array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'date')); 
    function filter_where($where = ''){
        $where .= " AND post_date < '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-8 month'))."'";
        return $where;
    }
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
    if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // your code
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

**Update:** May be this can help you.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'year'     => date('Y'), // for current year, date('Y')-1 for 1 year ago
    'monthnum' => $m, // the month in the loop
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, that worked great, hope you enjoy your points :) ! I'm now having a bit of trouble with the  code I used in my question above. It lists everything by month but it includes posts from previous years, how might I go about filtering out the older posts (older than 8 months) in this query? thank you again

Comment: If your code gets posts older than 8 months then it could be in the last year.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being very clear in previous comment. The question you gave an answer to, displays all of the news that's older than 8 months which is great. The other question was as follows. The custom query that I included in my original question, displays all of the news posts by month, but it doesn't remove the ones that are older than 8 months so for instance if I had a post in news from last august, it would appear in the current August list. is there any custom query i can use to remove these. (the query's in a for loop at the moment as i need to loop through months to print a nav menu

Comment: Do you want to display posts by month but only from current year ?

Comment: No, I just want to edit the query I wrote above so that it only includes posts from the last 8 months, currently it just pulls through any post that has the same monthnum so all posts are pulled through for August for instannce even if it was august 2009

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware of wordpress but can help you logically. As per my knowledge, This can be done by checking condition like "WHERE creation_date < 8 months" in your query while retriving posts for category 'older news'. So first get current date.

```
<?php $today = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

Then subtract 8 months from it and you will get a date 8 month older

```
<?php $eight_month = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-8 month $today")); ?>
```

now you can use $eight_month in your query so your query would be something like this. Check format of date you are storing in your database for post and change my accordingly if it is different than format "Y-m-d"

**"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creation_date < '$eight_month'"**

Hope this is what you want and help you in your project. Best luck and have a nice day